# implementing a method from one class to another?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a program for airplane seating arrangements for a class and i ended up making two `toString` methods but when I run the program the `toString` method in my airplane class is making something not work specifically:

```
str= str + seats[i][j].toString();
```

I believe that simply deleting the `toString` method in the seat class and somehow putting it back into the airplane class `toString` method would fix the problem or make it simpler. What's wrong?

#### Airplane class:

```
public class Airplane 
{
  private Seat [ ] [ ] seats;
  public static final int FIRST_CLASS = 1;
  public static final int ECONOMY = 2;
  private static final int FC_ROWS = 5;
  private static final int FC_COLS = 4;
  private static final int ECONOMY_ROWS = 5;
  private static final int ECONOMY_COLS = 6;

  public Airplane() 
  {
    seats  = new Seat[FC_ROWS][ECONOMY_COLS]; 
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    String str = "";
    for (int i=0; i<FC_ROWS; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<ECONOMY_COLS; j++) 
      {
        str= str + seats[i][j].toString();
      }
      str = str + "\n";
    }
    return str;
  }   

}
```

#### Seat Class:

```
public class Seat 
{
  private int seatType;
  private boolean isReserved;
  public static final int WINDOW = 1;
  public static final int AISLE = 2;
  public static final int CENTER = 3;

  public Seat(int inSeatType)
  {
    seatType = inSeatType;
    isReserved = false;
  }
  public int getSeatType()
  {
    return seatType;
  }

  public void reserveSeat()
  {
    isReserved = true;
  }
  public boolean isAvailable()
  {
    if (!isReserved)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else return false; 
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    if(isReserved == false)
    {
      return "*";
    }
    else return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: please show us your incorrect and correct output.

Comment: You didn't fix the `NPE` yet, since your post yesterday regarding this same piece of code. `str= str + seats[i][j].toString();` will throw a `NPE`, fix that first.

Comment: sorry R.J i am confused as to what an NPE is and how i would go about fixing it. but that is certainly the line of code that is giving me problems. Suggestions?

Comment: NullPointerException. Fix is to initialize it.....

Comment: a lot of you have been mentioning NPE and Thihara said to initialize it but how would i initialize the line of code str= str + seats[i][j].toString(); if this is a dumb question sorry i'm still learning the basics.

Comment: fixed it and thnx R.J. even though your answers were a bit confusing for my level of java at least you've helped me with all my questions on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In `Seat.toString` you should print a `" "` not `""`.
- You're array is `FC_ROWS` by `ECONOMY_COLS`, so you're not creating all the seats. You should probably have two arrays (one for FC, one for Economy), since `FC_ROWS != ECONOMY_ROWS`.
- You aren't actually creating `Seat`s in your constructor. Use a nested loop to create them, otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`. Creating an array doesn't create the objects contained in the array.

  - When you're creating the seats in the Airplane constructor, use `if` statements to figure out if the seat is supposed to be a Window, Aisle, etc.

Comment: for this project that is not important since the seats that are not there will later on be returned as asterisks. thanks thouhg

Comment: but if you call `.toString()` on `null` you will get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: alright yeah as i said many people have mentioned the NPE but i still have no idea how to fix it and could you show me how i would do it

Comment: idk if you had the best answer but it solved my problem thnx.

Answer (score 1):

`seats` seems to does not have `Seat`'s instance.

Add this code :

```
for (int i=0; i<FC_ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<ECONOMY_COLS; j++) 
    {
        seats[i][j] = new Seat();
    }
}
```

below this :

```
seats  = new Seat[FC_ROWS][ECONOMY_COLS];
```

Comment: that at least printed something out what happened though is it didnt like the Seat in new Seat() what i ended up doing was new Seat(Seat.WINDOW); i also tried center and aisle and what prints out is this:
Expected: 
EEEE
EEEE
EEEE
EEEE
EEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
Actual: 
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE
EEEEEE

Comment: I can not imagine your expected prints. Can you write your expected prints at the question instead of comments?

Comment: i fixed it. so dont worry about it basically what happened was i was only printing out my economy class not my first class i ended up typing a lot more code than needed but it got the job done. thnx anyways

Answer (score 0):

I think that in `Seat::toString`, you mean to return `" "` (a space) if it isn't reserved.

Comment: yeah i fixed that if it isnt reserved then i return E(empty) and then else return "*"(occupied) thanks for catching that. didnt fix the problem but definitely something that would've come up later.